# Resdhift specify multiple time periods

Tags: redshift

I use [redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) to regulate the levels of blue light of my display.

I like the program but it only lets me specify a `dawn-time` and a `dusk-time`, which limits the ability to configure the temperature throughout the day.

Is there a way to set other time intervals, for example one for the morning, one for the early afternoon, one for the late afternoon and one for the night?

My current config file, located in `~/.config/redshift/redshift.conf` as suggested in the man page is the following

```
[redshift]
dawn-time=06:50
dusk-time=18:00
temp-day=5400
temp-night=2300
gamma=0.8
```